# Extract Array values into object dynamically

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, dynamic-programming, javascript-objects

I want to create an algorithm that replicates values for this object schema (sample data here):

```
let layer1 = {name: 'x',
          values: [{_color: '#996666', time: 0, tween: 'quadEaseIn', value: 0},
                   {_color: '#b074a0', time: 4, value: 5.500023},
                   {_color: '#b074a0', time: 3, value: 4.500023},
                   {_color: '#b074a0', time: 2, value: 3.500023}],
          tmpValue: 3.500023,
          _color: '#6ee167',
          _value: 0};
```

The 3rd, 4th, and 5th line of this sample data is relevant to the problem.

So then below is the algorithm so far. The variable numKeyframes is already defined (n).  In the first loop, dynamic objects are added to an array called keyframes.

In the second loop, keyframes array is included within the layer object.  The idea here is that keyframes should insert multiple objects in place of the object it is within (just as the sample object data above).

```
  ...
  var keyframes = [];
  var timevals = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
  for (var k=0; k<numKeyframes; k++) {
    var tv = timevals[k];
    var kf = {_color: '#FF0000', time: tv, value: 3.500023}
    keyframes.push(kf);
  }

  // make x, y, z layers
  for (var i=0; i<3; i++) {
    layer =  {name: layerNames[i],
              values: [{_color: layerValuesColors[i],
                        time: layerValuesTime[i],
                        tween: 'quadEaseIn',
                        value: layerValuesValues[i]},
                        keyframes],
              tmpValue: layertmpValues[i],
              _color: layerColors2[i],
              _value: layerValues[i]}
    layerData.push(layer);
  }
  ...
```

But that does not work.  It appears that no objects are included.

If I replace keyframes], with keyframes[0]], then it works, but of course it only gets the first value (object), when all values (objects) need to be inserted.

What is the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you haven't any error in your code, all just to check the data structure using [console.dir](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/dir) function as following

```
console.dir(layerData);
```

Comment: correct, there is not error, and console.dir(layerData) does show objects ([object Object],[object Object],[object Object]) ... but it is the keyframes within layerData that I have the question of how to parse it correctly

Comment: Okay, I just tried this: console.dir("layerData: " + JSON.stringify(layerData));

Comment: which does show that the keyframes objects are being nested. for example, here is one of them:

Comment: [{"name":"x","values":[{"_color":"#996666","time":0,"tween":"quadEaseIn","value":0},[{"_color":"#FF0000","time":1,"value":3.500023},{"_color":"#FF0000","time":2,"value":3.500023},{"_color":"#FF0000","time":3,"value":3.500023}]],"tmpValue":3.500023,"_color":"#6ee167","_value":0},

Comment: but why is this putting quotations around object keys?  for example "values" and "time":2 ?  this needs to be exactly like the sample data i showed at the top of the post.

Comment: and it is also including an extra set of brackets around the keyframes object, when none is needed.  this is not producing any error, but it is not processing correctly in other parts of my application.  it needs to be just like the sample at top

Comment: change the portion
`values: [{_color: layerValuesColors[i],
                        time: layerValuesTime[i],
                        tween: 'quadEaseIn',
                        value: layerValuesValues[i]},
                        keyframes],`
with
`values: [{_color: layerValuesColors[i],
                        time: layerValuesTime[i],
                        tween: 'quadEaseIn',
                        value: layerValuesValues[i]}
                        ].concat(keyframes),`